# Transaction percentage total count in Stata

Tags: stata

Here is a sales transactions data set in Stata format. Each row is a sale of

- a specific product
- in a specific week
- at a specific store
- in a specific city

Some products were not sold at all stores in all weeks for a given city. For all products, I would like to calculate their market availability in that city in percentage points given certain week. For example, if product A was sold in week 1 in **half** of all the distinct stores in city (# of available stores changing from week to week), a new column would indicate market availability of 50% for all those observations (count). For different example, in the following sample data set for week 1, my desired variable market_availability would look like this (ignore the unit_sold column for now):

```
week   store   SKU     city  units_sold mkt_avail
 1    200059 01182007   C        5      1
 1    200060 01182007   C        4      1
 1    200061 01182007   C        4      1
 1    200060 01182090   C        6      0.66
 1    200059 01182090   C        4      0.66
 1    200061 01182888   C        1      0.33

 2    200059 01182007   K       4       1
 2    200060 01182007   K       1       1
 2    200061 01182007   K       4       1
 2    200059 01182090   K       8       0.66
 2    200060 01182090   K       9       0.66
 2    200061 01182888   K       4       0.33
```

This is a Stata table:

```
clear
set more off
input str5 week str8 store str30 SKU units_sold str1 city
 1 200059 01182007 5 C
 1 200059 01182090 4 C
 1 200060 01182007 4 C
 1 200060 01182090 6 C
 1 200061 01182007 4 C
 1 200061 01182888 1 C
 2 200059 01182007 4 K      
 2 200060 01182007 1 K      
 2 200061 01182007 4 K      
 2 200059 01182090 8 K      
 2 200060 01182090 9 K      
 2 200061 01182888 4 K     
 end
```

The problem is that in this transactions data set, the same week store city SKU combinations can appear several times because of repeated purchases; but we don't want to consider repeated observations in the calculation of our shares because we already know that a specific item was available at that time.

I begin with tagging the unique observations by week and city

```
egen tag = tag(week city)
```

I also try

```
egen tag1 = tag(store SKU)
```

Now, should I try and match them up together?

Logically, I think I need first, to sum up distinct counts of city/ week/ store /SKU; then I need to calculate the number of stores in the city/week if SKU was ever sold for that combination. And then divide the first number by the second. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy seems good. You can tag distinct (not "unique") observations just once in two ways and then calculate a fraction by dividing totals. This can all be done without any file choreography. The assumption here is that there are no observations recording zero sales. But if there are, then adding `if units_sold` to the `tag()` calculations should be sufficient to ignore them.

```
. clear

. set more off

. input str5 week str8 store str30 SKU units_sold str1 city

          week      store                             SKU  units_s~d       city
  1.  1 200059 01182007 5 C
  2.  1 200059 01182090 4 C
  3.  1 200060 01182007 4 C
  4.  1 200060 01182090 6 C
  5.  1 200061 01182007 4 C
  6.  1 200061 01182888 1 C
  7.  2 200059 01182007 4 K      
  8.  2 200060 01182007 1 K      
  9.  2 200061 01182007 4 K      
 10.  2 200059 01182090 8 K      
 11.  2 200060 01182090 9 K      
 12.  2 200061 01182888 4 K     
 13.  end

. egen tag = tag(city week store SKU)

. egen stores_selling_product = total(tag), by(city week SKU)

. egen tag2 = tag(city week store)

. egen stores_in_city = total(tag2), by(city week)

. gen fraction = stores_sell/stores_in

. sort week SKU store

. l week store SKU city stores* fraction , sepby(week)

     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | week    store        SKU   city   stores~t   stores~y   fraction |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1   200059   01182007      C          3          3          1 |
  2. |    1   200060   01182007      C          3          3          1 |
  3. |    1   200061   01182007      C          3          3          1 |
  4. |    1   200059   01182090      C          2          3   .6666667 |
  5. |    1   200060   01182090      C          2          3   .6666667 |
  6. |    1   200061   01182888      C          1          3   .3333333 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------|
  7. |    2   200059   01182007      K          3          3          1 |
  8. |    2   200060   01182007      K          3          3          1 |
  9. |    2   200061   01182007      K          3          3          1 |
 10. |    2   200059   01182090      K          2          3   .6666667 |
 11. |    2   200060   01182090      K          2          3   .6666667 |
 12. |    2   200061   01182888      K          1          3   .3333333 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On the terminology of *distinct* and *unique* in Stata context, and more importantly a review of technique in this territory, see [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042).

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you Nick! The code is working very well with the data set.

Comment: Thanks for the closure!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this solution is not the best, but would work as your wish:

```
save original,replace                                                        // keeping your original dataset
collapse (count)has_sold=units_sold if units_sold>0, by(week store SKU city) // make binary flag for counting 
replace has_sold=1                                                           // force binary flag
save tmp,replace                                                             // preserving current status
bysort week store: keep if _n==1 
egen numStoreWeekly = count(has_sold), by(week)                              // get total number of stores in week regardless city
drop SKU has_sold                                                            // dropping temporary variables
merge m:m week store city using tmp                                          // adding numStoreWeekly to tmp.dta ("merge m:m" was used to assign same numStoreWeekly to same week/store/city combination)
egen numStoreSold = count(has_sold), by(week city SKU)                       // counting stores sold by week city SKU
gen mkt_avail = numStoreSold/numStoreWeekly
drop numStoreSold numStoreWeekly _merge has_sold                             // dropping temporary variables
merge m:m week store city SKU using original                                 // merging back (adding mkt_avail to original.dta )
drop _merge
sort week city SKU store
```

Comment: The documented syntax is `merge m:m` and Stata warns against this kind of `merge`. Indeed, it's a puzzle why such merges are supported.

Comment: @NickCox Of course this code was tested. (OSX, Stata/MP 13.1) Thanks for your elegant solution.

Comment: I don't see a comment on your use of `merge n:n`. If that worked, it's undocumented syntax and an explanation would be appropriate.

Comment: @NickCox I added comments to `merge n:n` as your suggestion.

Comment: I am surprised that Stata accepts `n:n` instead of `m:m`.

Comment: @NickCox Now I can understand your point. `n:n` was my mistake, but surprisingly, `merge n:n` worked with no error. I will correct `merge n:n` to `merge m:m`

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks.